# Collar bone visibility issue

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, muscle-mass, shoulders

I've been following a bodyweight training routine for 2 months now and I'm satisfied with the gains until now.
I am training to improve how I look, and I've succeeded till now except for my shoulder. My collar bone is very visible and it makes me look very skinny despite being in a good shape.

Some people told me that my upper chest needs some workout. I don't know if it was true. So, what muscle do I have to train to make it less visible ?
Please, suggest some workouts for the upper chest if it was the muscle that I have to train. I do only bodyweight exercises.

Comment: Sounds more like posture and mobility issue than needing to hide jacked up should position behind even more muscle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is more muscle you are looking for then bodyweight exercises are probably not the best idea. You will gain size, but only to a point. If you want results then going to the gym is your best option. A combination of overhead pressing and bench pressing will give you the upper chest development that you seek. I would suggest a barbell based strength program to achieve best results in the shortest space of time. Lift big to get big. There is no easy option unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I was looking for. But there IS an easy option. Handstand push ups and one arm push ups are not easy.

Comment: @Peter You say that but the answer is correct in that again these are limited. You need to lift more weight to get bigger. This is sadly inescapable even doing handstand pushups